# $C^z - (C-1)^z = A^x$ : I am trying to prove that If $z$ is any prime number greater than $3$ then the only way $x$ can be prime is $x=2$ or $x=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

According to Fermat's last theorem: $A^x + B^x = C^x$ for any integer value of $x$ greater than $2$ is impossible. It was proven by Andrew Wiles in 1994.

A more generalized conjecture known as the Beal's conjecture states that if $A^x + B^y = C^z$, where $A, B, C, x, y$ and $z$ are positive integers and $x, y$ and $z$ are all greater than $2$, then $A, B$ and $C$ must have a common prime factor.

I am interested in a specific case of $A^x + B^y = C^z$ where $B = C - 1$ and $y = z$. So it means $A^x + (C-1)^z = C^z$ or we can see it as $C^z - (C-1)^z = A^x$.

I am trying to prove that If $z$ is any prime number greater than $3$ then the only way $x$ can be prime is $x=2$ or $x=3$

If I disobey the rules and set $z = 2$, I have as an example:

$5^2 - 4^2 =3^2$

If I disobey the rules and set only $x = 2$, I have as an example (which are very rare):

$8^3 - 7^3 = 13^2$

**To begin I will show the properties:**

According to Fermat's little theorem when $x$ is prime greater than $2$: ​

$(A^x - A) \bmod x = 0$

$(A^x - A) \bmod 6 = 0$

And when $x$ is greater than 3, also:

$(A^x - A) \bmod (x ⋅6)  = 0$

And for obvious reasons:

$(A^x - A) \bmod A  = 0$

- Update per the given answers in another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088256/ax-a-bmod-a-1-2-0-and-ax-a-bmod-a-1-21-0-when-x-and/4088305#4088305)

Also:

$(A^x-A) \bmod ((A-1)/2) = 0$ and $(A^x-A) \bmod ((A-1)/2)+1 = 0$

**When $C^2$**

$1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2,6^2,7^2,8^2,9^2,10^2 ...$

$1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100 ...$

Growing at:

$1+3+5+7+9+11+13+15+17+19...$ Let me denote any number in the list as $D$, which basically means $C^2 - (C-1)^2 = D$

- Notice that what all the $D$'s have in common is the fact that $(D-1) \bmod 2 =0$

**When $C^3$**

$1^3,2^3,3^3,4^3,5^3,6^3,7^3,8^3,9^3,10^3 ...$

$1,8,27,64,125,216,343,512,729,1000 ...$

Growing at:

$7+19+37+61+91+127+169+217+271...$ Let me denote any number in the list as $D$, which basically means $C^3 - (C-1)^3 = D$

- Notice that what all the $D$'s have In common is the fact that $(D-1) \bmod 6 =0$

Remember According to Fermat's little theorem when $x$ is prime greater than $2$: ​

$(A^x - A) \bmod x = 0$

$(A^x - A) \bmod 6 = 0$

And when $x$ is greater than 3, also:

$(A^x - A) \bmod (x ⋅6)  = 0$

And for obvious reasons:

$(A^x - A) \bmod A  = 0$

- Update per the given answers in another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088256/ax-a-bmod-a-1-2-0-and-ax-a-bmod-a-1-21-0-when-x-and/4088305#4088305)

Also:

$(A^x-A) \bmod ((A-1)/2) = 0$ and $(A^x-A) \bmod ((A-1)/2)+1 = 0$

Since we have $(D-1) \bmod 6 =0$, If we want $D=A^x$
it leaves us with the only possibilities for $A^x$ to be $A = 7,13,19,25,31...$, but as far as $x$ goes, $x$ can be anything. I am incapable to dismiss these possibilities.

**But here is the thing** it starts becoming interesting when $z$ is any prime greater than $3$ (thus not having the same factors of $6$)

**When $C^5$:**

$1^5,2^5,3^5,4^5,5^5,6^5,7^5,8^5,9^5,10^5 ...$

$1,32,243,1024,3125,7776,16807,32768,59049,100000 ...$

Growing at:

$31+211+781+2101+4651+9031+15961+26281+40951...$ Let me denote any number in the list as $D$, which basically means $C^5 - (C-5)^5 = D$

Notice that what all the $D$'s have In common is the fact that $(D-1) \bmod 5 =0$ and $(D-1) \bmod 6 =0$ and $(D-1) \bmod 30 =0$

The only possibilities for $D=A^x$ are if  $A = 7,13,19,25,31...$ but the problem is that also $(D-1) \bmod 5 =0$ and $(D-1) \bmod 6 =0$ which means $(D-6) \bmod 5 =0$ , $(D-11) \bmod 5 =0$ , $(D-16) \bmod 5 =0$... and $(D-7) \bmod 6 =0$ , $(D-13) \bmod 6 =0$ , $(D-19) \bmod 6 =0$....

Replacing $D$ with $A^x$ leaves us with the only possibilities for $A^x$ to be $(A^x-1) \bmod 5 =0$  and $(A^x-1) \bmod 6 =0$ which for most of the possibilities are contradicting  Fermat's little theorems for $A^x$ has to be $(A^x-A) \bmod A = 0$ and $(A^x-A) \bmod 6 = 0$ when the only possibilities to begin with are $A = 7,13,19,25,31...$

Per @mathlove's comment we are left only with the possibilities : $31, 61, 91...$

- Update per the given answers in another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088256/ax-a-bmod-a-1-2-0-and-ax-a-bmod-a-1-21-0-when-x-and/4088305#4088305)

Also:

$(A^x-A) \bmod ((A-1)/2) = 0$ and $(A^x-A) \bmod ((A-1)/2)+1 = 0$

But when I try checking $D$ as a possible $A^x$ with the value of $31$, I get :

$31- 31 \bmod 15 ≠ 0$ and $31 - 31 \bmod 16 ≠ 0$

$211 - 31 \bmod 15 = 0$ and $211 - 31 \bmod 16 ≠ 0$

$781 - 31 \bmod 15 = 0$ and $781 - 31 \bmod 16 ≠ 0$

...

The same happens when I check $D$ against $61,91,121...$

I don't know if it holds true and how to prove it but so far I haven't found any counter examples where both conditions are met, Maybe there is a way to prove this?

Another Example: **When $C^7$:**

$1^7,2^7,3^7,4^7,5^7,6^7,7^7,8^7,9^7,10^7 ...$

$1,128,2187,16384,78125, 279936 ,823543, 2097152 ,4782969 ,10000000 ...$

Growing at:

$127+2059+14197+61741+201811+543607+1273609+2685817+5217031...$ Let me denote any number in the list as $D$, which basically means $C^7 - (C-7)^7 = D$

The only possibilities for $D=A^x$ are if  $A = 7,13,19,25,31...$ but the problem is that also $(D-1) \bmod 7 =0$ and $(D-1) \bmod 6 =0$ which means $(D-8) \bmod 7 =0$ , $(D-15) \bmod 7 =0$ , $(D-22) \bmod 7 =0$... and $(D-7) \bmod 6 =0$ , $(D-13) \bmod 6 =0$ , $(D-19) \bmod 6 =0$....

Replacing $D$ with $A^x$ leaves us with the only possibilities for $A^x$ to be $(A^x-1) \bmod 7 =0$  and $(A^x-1) \bmod 6 =0$ which is contradicting Fermat's little theorem for most of the possibilities because $A^x$ has to be $(A^x-A) \bmod A = 0$ and $(A^x-A) \bmod 6 = 0$ when the only possibilities to begin with are $A = 7,13,19,25,31...$

Per @mathlove's comment we are left only with the possibilities : $ 43, 85, 127...$

- Update per the given answers in another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088256/ax-a-bmod-a-1-2-0-and-ax-a-bmod-a-1-21-0-when-x-and/4088305#4088305)

Also:

$(A^x-A) \bmod ((A-1)/2) = 0$ and $(A^x-A) \bmod ((A-1)/2)+1 = 0$

But when I try checking $D$ as a possible $A^x$ with the value of $43$, I get :

$127 - 43 \bmod 21 = 0$ and $127 - 43 \bmod 22  ≠ 0$

$2059  - 43 \bmod 21 = 0$ and $2059 - 43 \bmod 22 ≠ 0$

$14197 - 43 \bmod 21 = 0$ and $14197 - 43 \bmod 22 ≠ 0$

...

The same happens when I check $D$ against $85,127,169...$

I don't know if it holds true always and how to prove it but so far I haven't found any counter examples where both conditions are met.

**My question is broken into:**

I have updated the question since @mathlove's comments proved me wrong for my initial question.

- Am I correct in regard to the remaining  possibilities and is there any way to eliminate these remaining possibilities?

Comment: "The only possibilities for $D=A^x$ are if  $A = 7,13,19,25,31...$ but the problem is that also $(D-1) \bmod 5 =0$ which means $(D-6) \bmod 5 =0$ which means $(D-6) \bmod 6 =0$." Why does $(D-6) \bmod 5 =0$ mean $(D-6) \bmod 6 =0$ ?

Comment: @mathlove you are correct. I have edited the question.

Comment: I don't get "Replacing $D$ with $A^x$ leaves us with the only possibilities for $A^x$ to be $(A^x-1) \bmod 5 =0$  and $(A^x-1) \bmod 6 =0$ which is contradicting  Fermat's little theorems for $A^x$ has to be $(A^x-A) \bmod A = 0$ and $(A^x-A) \bmod 6 = 0$ when the only possibilities to begin with are $A = 7,13,19,25,31...$" If $A=31$, then for any $x\ge 1$, we have $(A^x-1) \bmod 5 =0$, $(A^x-1) \bmod 6 =0$, $(A^x-A) \bmod A = 0$ and $(A^x-A) \bmod 6 = 0$, so I think that there is no contradiction.

Comment: @mathlove as always you are the correct. I re-edited

Comment: @mathlove I think I have met a way to limit even further the possibilities, with an answer I have received here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088256/ax-a-bmod-a-1-2-0-and-ax-a-bmod-a-1-21-0-when-x-and. Only if you have time,  can you comment with your opinion.

Comment: "$211 - 31 \bmod 15 = 0$ and $211 - 31 \bmod 16 ≠ 0$" Where did the $211$ come from?

Comment: @mathlove $211$ is an example of $D$

Comment: @mathlove I am assuming that there is a possibility that $31^x=211$  and I thought maybe since the heuristic shows that sometimes $D-31 \bmod 16 =0$ and sometimes $D-31 \bmod 15=0$ but never both, that  maybe there is a way to prove it based on the properties of $D$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written

> $211 - 31 \bmod 15 = 0$ and $211 - 31 \bmod 16 ≠ 0$
> $781 - 31 \bmod 15 = 0$ and $781 - 31 \bmod 16 ≠ 0$
> The same happens when I check $D$ against $61,91,121...$
> I don't know if it holds true and how to prove it but so far I haven't found any counter examples where both conditions are met, Maybe there is a way to prove this?

There is a counterexample.

If $C=18$, then we have

$$D-31=18^5-17^5-31=15\times 16\times 1957$$

from which we get
$$D-31\equiv 0\pmod{15}\qquad\text{and}\qquad D-31\equiv 0\pmod{16}$$

Comment: I guess it is a dead end.  I greatly appreciate all your time and effort

Comment: I just want to add that you are correct about that possibility even though by checking it manually  for $469680 \bmod 31 ≠ 0$ but I am out of ways to reject such possibilities .

Comment: @Isaac Brenig : You are welcome. If $C=95$, then we have $D-31=15\times 16\times 31\times 53598$.

Comment: wow completely debunked. I don’t know how you do it, but again greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Isaac Brenig : I used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5-%28x-1%29%5E5-31%3D0+mod%287440%29&lang=en).