# $(A^x-A) \bmod ((A-1)/2) = 0$ and $(A^x-A) \bmod (((A-1)/2)+1)= 0$ when $x$ and $A$ are odd positive integers greater than $1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I was studying Fermat's little theorem which states that if $x$ if prime, we have:

$(A^x-A) \bmod (x)=0$

$(A^x-A) \bmod (6)=0$

And obviously:

$(A^x-A) \bmod (A)=0$

I wanted to see if there are any other interesting properties and I found the following:

Regardless to if $x$ is prime, when both $A$ and $x$ are odd integers greater than $1$

$(A^x-A) \bmod ((A-1)/2) = 0$ and $(A^x-A) \bmod (((A-1)/2)+1) = 0$

Random Examples:

$(13^7-13) \bmod (6)=0$ and $(13^7-13) \bmod (7)=0$

$(21^5-21) \bmod (10)=0$  and  $(21^5-21) \bmod (11)=0$

$(47^{11}-47) \bmod (23)=0$  and  $(47^{11} -47) \bmod (24)=0$

$(59^3-59) \bmod (29)=0$  and  $(59^3-59) \bmod (30)=0$

$(61^{11}-61) \bmod (30)=0$ and  $(61^{11}-61) \bmod (31)=0$

$(35^{13}-35) \bmod (17)=0$ and  $(35^{13}-35) \bmod (18)=0$

Am I correct about this or are there any counterexamples? If I am correct Is there a proof or an explanation in regards to why it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is an odd integer and $x$ is a nonnegative integer, then
\begin{align*}
&
A^x\equiv A\;\left(\text{mod}\;\Bigl(\frac{A-1}{2}\Bigr)\right)
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
(2)(A^x)\equiv 2A\;\Bigl(\text{mod}\;(A-1)\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
(2)(1^x)\equiv (2)(1)\;\Bigl(\text{mod}\;(A-1)\Bigr)
\qquad\Bigl[\text{since $A\equiv 1 \;\Bigl(\text{mod}\;(A-1)\Bigr)$}\,\Bigr]
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
2\equiv 2\;\Bigl(\text{mod}\;(A-1)\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is true.

Similarly, if $A$ is an odd integer and $x$ is an odd positive integer, then
\begin{align*}
&
A^x\equiv A\;\left(\text{mod}\;\Bigl(\frac{A+1}{2}\Bigr)\right)
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
(2)(A^x)\equiv 2A\;\Bigl(\text{mod}\;(A+1)\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
(2)\bigl((-1)^x\bigr)\equiv (2)(-1)\;\Bigl(\text{mod}\;(A+1)\Bigr)
\qquad\Bigl[\text{since $A\equiv -1 \;\Bigl(\text{mod}\;(A+1)\Bigr)$}\,\Bigr]
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
-2\equiv -2\;\Bigl(\text{mod}\;(A+1)\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is true.

Comment: @Isaac Brenig: I don't see a clear, single question in that post.

Answer (score 1):

$(A^x - A) = A(A^{(x-1)} - 1).$

Since $(x-1)$ is an even number,
$(A^{(x-1)} - 1)$ has $(A^2 - 1) = (A+1)(A-1)$ as a divisor.

Therefore, since $A$ is odd,

$(A+1)/2$ and $(A-1)/2$ are divisors.

Comment: Just because their's was more detailed, but your answer was valid to begin with.and I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a way to use this info in one of my other question, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086432/cz-c-1z-ax-i-am-trying-to-prove-that-if-z-is-any-prime-number-gre?noredirect=1#comment8447137_4086432

Comment: @IsaacBrenig Sorry, that would take me several hours of study to try to determine.