# Why does $(A^x+B^y) \bmod (A+B) = 0$ when $B = A+2$ or $B=A-2$ and when $x≠y$ for the following?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

As a self learner, these are my observations:

When $x$ is any odd positive integer greater than $1$ and $A$ and $B$ are any positive integers greater than $1$, we have:

$(A^x + B^x) \bmod (A+B) = 0$

In order to understand it to myself, I visualized it with numbers in such way:

$13^3 = 13+39+65+91+117+143+169+195+221+247+273+299+325$

$7^3 = 7+21+35+49+63+70+77$

$13^3+7^3= (20+60+100+140+180+220+260)+(195+221+247+299+325)$

The reason why I used the parentheses is just to emphasize how i added the $7$ numbers used to sum $7^3$ to the $7$ first numbers used to sum $13^3$ and the remaining $6$ numbers used to sum $13^3$.

When $x$ and $y$ are any odd positive integers greater than $1$ and $x≠y$, and $A$ and $B$ are any positive integers greater than $1$, we have:

$(A^x + B^y) \bmod (A+B) = 0$ when $B = A+2$ or $B=A-2$

In order to understand it to myself, I visualized it with numbers in such way:

When $B ≠ A+2$ and $B ≠ A-2$

$13^3 = 13+39+65+91+117+143+169+195+221+247+273+299+325$

$7^5 = 343+1029+1715+2401+3087+3773+4459$

$13^3+7^3= (356+1068+1780+2492+3204+3916+4628)+(195+221+247+299+325)$

So now I have a problem because the sum of the additions in the first parentheses is divisible by $356$ and the sum of the additions in the second parentheses is divisible by $20$ and $356$ is not divisible by $20$.

Edit: per one of the comments, that is not to say that there are no cases where $(A^x + B^y) \bmod (A+B) = 0$ when $B ≠ A+2$ or $B≠ A-2$.

When $B = A+2$ and $B = A-2$:

$6^7 = 7776 + 23328 + 38880 + 54432 + 69984 + 85536$

$8^3 = 8 + 24+ 40 + 56 +72 +88 +104 + 120$

$6^7+8^3= (7784+23352+38920+54488+70056+86624)+(104+120)$

The addition in the second parentheses is exactly the same as if it would of been in the case of $6^5+8^5$ which is divisible by $14$ so the only thing left to do is check if the first number in the first parentheses is also divisible by $14$ and as it turns: $7784 \bmod 14 = 0$.

The first number in the additions that sum to $6^7$ is $7776$ which is equal to $6^5$ and the first number in  the additions that sum to $8^3$ is $8^1$ which brings me all the way back to ground zero...

As a self learner, I tried searching for an answer and couldn't. If this has an answer in a similar question, please close and refer. Any references are appreciated.

Why does $(A^x+B^y) \bmod (A+B) = 0$ when $B = A+2$ or $B=A-2$ and when $x≠y$?

Comment: Hint: $A^{2k+1}+B^{2k+1}=(A+B)(B^0A^{2k}-BA^{2k-1}+B^2A^{2k-2}-...+B^{2k+1}A^0)$

Comment: @IsaacBrenig There are cases where $(A^x + B^y) \equiv 0 \pmod{A + B}$ for odd $x$ and $y$  with $x \neq y$ but where $B \neq A + 2$ and $B \neq A - 2$. For example, for any odd $y$, note that $(5^{4 + y} + 8^{y}) \equiv 0 \pmod{5 + 8}$.

Comment: @John Omielan I have reedited the question per your comment.

Comment: @aristotlefromgreece Note that the exponents are *unequal* in the question so it's not clear how your comment pertains. It's easy to reduce it to two well-known divisibilities, viz. $\,\color{darkorange}2\mid A(A\pm 1)\,$ and $\,A^2-1\mid \color{#0a0}{A^{2n}-1},\,$  e.g. see my answer.

Comment: I just noticed this is related to the [your question two months ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4088256/242). What are you trying to solve with these results?

Comment: @Bill Dubuque you are correct, they are related and unfortunately I am still at the level where I can see the connections only with the answers I get.  In this case, it has to do with my fascination of Fermat’s last theorem, but in no way am I even thinking that I can solve it, or even understand WIle’s proof. I just try to understand as much I can.

Comment: I see. Btw, you may find helpful my comment on John's answer, which uses the first two terms of Taylor's formula (vs. first two terms of Binomial Theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B=A+2$. Then $A+B=2(A+1)$. Modulo $2(A+1)$, $A^x+B^y=A^x+(A+2)^y=A^x+(-A)^y=A^x-A^y$. Now $A^2\equiv1\bmod{2(A+1)}$ because $A^2-1=2(A+1){A-1\over2}$, so $A^x-A^y\equiv0\bmod{2(A+1)}$.

Similarly for $B=A-2$.

EDIT: Bill points out that I made the unjustified assumption that $A$ is odd. So, suppose $A$ is even. Then $A^2\equiv1\bmod{A+1}$, and $A^x-A^y\equiv0\bmod2$, and $\gcd(2,A+1)=1$, so again $A^x-A^y\equiv0\bmod{2(A+1)}$.

Comment: The argument implicitly assumes $A$ is odd, without any justification (note OP gives an example with $A$ even).

Comment: We can avoid the parity case analysis by working mod $\,A^3-A$ vs. $\,A^2-1,\,$ see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply $\,\ \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\color{darkorange}2(A\pm1)\mid A^3\!-A\mid \color{#0a0}{A^k (A^{2n}\!-1)}}\ $ if $\,k,n>0,\,$ as we prove below.

$\ \ \ \ \ \overbrace{\bmod A\!+\!B\!:}^{\textstyle \color{#c00}{ B\:\!\equiv -A_{\phantom{|}}\!\!}\!\!\!\!} \ \ \ \ \overbrace{A^x + \color{#c00}B^y}^{\textstyle A^x\!+\!(\color{#c00}{-A})^y\!\!\!\!\!}\equiv\, \color{#0a0}{A^y(A^{x-y}\!-\!1)}\ $ by $\,y\,$ odd, wlog $\,x\!>\!y$.

$\ \underbrace{A\!+\!B = \color{darkorange}2(A\!+\!1)}_{\large  B\ =\ A\,+\,2}\mid \underbrace{A(A^2\!-\!1)}_{\large \color{darkorange}2\,\mid\, A(A-1)}\mid\color{#0a0}{A^y(A^{x-y}\!-\!1)}\ $ by $\,\begin{align}&A\mid \color{#0a0}{A^y}\ \ {\rm by}\,\ y\ge 1\\[.2em] &A^2\!-\!1\mid \color{#0a0}{A^{x-y}\!-\!1}\ \ {\rm by}\,\ \smash{\underbrace{2\mid\color{#0a0}{x\!-\!y}}_{\large x,y\,\ \rm odd}}\end{align}$

Comment: Same argument works for $\,B = A-2\,$ since then also  $\,A+B = 2(A-1)\mid A(A^2-1)\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Consider $B = A + 2$. This gives

$$A + B = A + (A + 2) = 2(A + 1) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Then for some integer $e \ge 0$ and odd positive integer $f$, we have

$$A + 1 = 2^{e}(f) \implies 2(A + 1) = 2^{e+1}(f), \; \; A = 2^{e}(f) - 1, \; \; B = 2^{e}(f) + 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

For any odd integers $x$ and $y$ greater than $1$, the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
A^{x} + B^{y} & = (2^{e}(f) - 1)^{x} + (2^{e}(f) + 1)^{y} \\
& = \left((2^{e}(f))^{x} - x(2^{e}(f))^{x-1} + \ldots + x(2^{e}(f)) - 1\right) + \\
& \; \; \; \; \; \left((2^{e}(f))^{y} + y(2^{e}(f))^{y-1} + \ldots + y(2^{e}(f)) + 1\right) \\
& = \left((2^{e}(f))^{x} - x(2^{e}(f))^{x-1} + \ldots - \frac{x(x-1)}{2}(2^{e}(f))^2\right) + \\
& \; \; \; \; \; \left((2^{e}(f))^{y} + y(2^{e}(f))^{y-1} + \ldots + \frac{y(y-1)}{2}(2^{e}(f))^2\right) + \\
& \; \; \; \; \; \left(x(2^{e}(f)) + y(2^{e}(f))\right) + (-1 + 1) \\
& = 2^{e}(f)\left[\left((2^{e}(f))^{x-1} - x(2^{e}(f))^{x-2} + \ldots - \frac{x(x-1)}{2}(2^{e}(f))\right)\right. + \\
& \; \; \; \; \; \left.\left((2^{e}(f))^{y-1} + y(2^{e}(f))^{y-2} + \ldots + \frac{y(y-1)}{2}(2^{e}(f))\right) + x + y\right]
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since this proves $2^{e}(f) \mid A^x + B^y$, we just need to show the part inside the square brackets in \eqref{eq3A} after $2^{e}(f)$ is even. If $e = 0$, then $A$ and $B$ are even, so $A^x + B^y$ and the part in the square brackets are even as well. If $e \gt 0$, then $x + y$ is even and all other terms inside the square brackets are even. Thus, in either case, we get that

$$2^{e+1}(f) \mid A^x + B^y \implies A^x + B^y \equiv 0 \pmod{A + B} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

For $B = A - 2 \implies A = B + 2$, note it's just basically the same as before with $A$ and $B$, plus $x$ and $y$, switched around.

---

There are many cases where odd integers $x \neq y$, with $A \gt 1$, $B \gt 1$, $B \neq A + 2$ and $B \neq A - 2$, but with $A^x + B^y \equiv A + B$. One fairly general case is to have $A + B = p$ for some odd prime $p$. Using the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order), let

$$m = \operatorname{ord}_{p}(A) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

which means $A^{m} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. If $m$ is even, then let $n = m$, else have $n = 2m$, so $A^{n} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ in either case. Then for any positive integer $k$, have $x = kn + y$ to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
A^{x} + B^{y} & \equiv A^{kn + y} + B^{y} \\
& \equiv (A^{n})^{k}A^{y} + B^{y} \\
& \equiv A^{y} + B^{y} \\
& \equiv (A + B)(A^{y-1} - A^{y-2}B + \ldots - AB^{y-2} + B^{y-1}) \\
& \equiv 0 \pmod{A + B}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

An example is a generalization of my question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170627/why-does-axby-bmod-ab-0-when-b-a2-or-b-a-2-and-when-x%e2%89%a0y-fo?noredirect=1#comment8638828_4170627), i.e., that $5^{4k + y} + 8^{y} \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$. Note the above procedure can also be done with $B$ instead of $A$.

In addition, with [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), we get that $n \mid p - 1$, which means that

$$A^{k(p-1) + y} + B^{y} \equiv A^{x} + B^{k(p-1) + x} \equiv 0 \pmod{A + B} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Comment: Clearer: $\,2\mid n\Rightarrow 2n\mid f(n)=(n\!-\!1)^x\!+(n\!+\!1)^y = \color{darkorange}{f(0)}+\color{#0a0}{f'(0)}\,n+ g(n)\,\color{#c00}{n^2},\,\ g(n)\in\Bbb Z[n],\,$ by $\,2n\mid \color{darkorange}{f(0)}=(-1)^x+1=0\,$ by $x$ odd, and $\,2n\mid \color{#c00}{n^2}\,$ by $\,2\mid n,\,$ and  $\,  \ 2\mid \color{#0a0}{f'(0)} = x(-1)^{x-1}+y\equiv x+y\equiv 0\pmod{\!2}\,$ by $\,x,y\,$ odd. $\ $ Above $\, n = 2^e f\ \ $